# Cygwin Make Just Keeps Entering Directory when making sip package

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cygwin, python-sip

I am trying to install sip as per the instructions [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html). I've installed Cygwin to allow me to use the `make` command in Windows (I'm using Windows 10). I run the configure.py file, and this creates a Makefile. I then run `make` from the Cygwin terminal, and all it does is print over and over again

```
make
make[####]: Entering directory 'cygdrive/c/Users/****/sip-4.19.13'
cd sipgen
```

Where `####` keeps increasing with every iteration.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not reported exactly how you did the things;
the following works for me:

```
$ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.19.13/sip-4.19.13.tar.gz 
....
2018-11-09 18:05:09 (149 KB/s) - ‘sip-4.19.13.tar.gz’ saved [1038815/1038815]
$ tar -xf sip-4.19.13.tar.gz 
$ cd  sip-4.19.13 
$ python2 configure.py 
This is SIP 4.19.13 for Python 2.7.14 on cygwin. 
The SIP code generator will be installed in /usr/bin. 
The sip.h header file will be installed in /usr/include/python2.7. 
The sip module will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages. 
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages. 
The default directory to install .sip files in is /usr/share/sip. 
Creating sipconfig.py... 
Creating top level Makefile... 
Creating sip code generator Makefile... 
Creating sip module Makefile... 
$ make 
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/tmp/sip-4.19.13/sipgen' 
gcc -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -DNDEBUG -I. -o main.o main.c 
... 
g++ -shared -o sip.dll siplib.o apiversions.o descriptors.o qtlib.o threads.o objmap.o voidptr.o array.o int_convertors.o bool.o -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/d/cyg_pub/tmp/sip-4.19.13/siplib'
```

so what steps were different for you ?

Comment: Additional please note that cygwin has already `python2-sip` and `python3-sip` packages